# GAE + JAXB... All right in local, not when deploy to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, jaxb

I try to create a application with Spring MVC in GAE. I need response a XML and use JAXB to do it. The response object is complex (contais interfaces), but all works fine in my local. The problem is when i deploy to App Engine. The responses of my request throw this exception (when complex object, simple objects work fine):

```
    Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.InternalError
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:53)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.isApplicable(PropertyInfoImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.getApplicableAdapter(PropertyInfoImpl.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.<init>(PropertyInfoImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ERPropertyInfoImpl.<init>(ERPropertyInfoImpl.java:53)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl.<init>(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.<init>(RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:59)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.createElementProperty(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.addProperty(ClassInfoImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:405)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:330)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:233)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:410)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:594)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.getJaxbContext(AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.createMarshaller(AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.writeWithMessageConverters(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:975)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.handleResponseBody(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:933)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.getModelAndView(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:483)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:490)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:777)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:754)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:345)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:337)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

EDIT: I add the structure of the response...I try to do Strategy pattern.

MyRequestController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/.myrequestX")
public class MyRequestController 
{

    @Autowired
    private GenericResponse response;

    @Autowired
    private X_ResponseBehaviorImpl valorDTO;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object getRespuesta(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req)
    {  
      // Other parts of code...


      response.getResponseBehavior().setResponse(valorDTO);
      return response;
    }

}
```

GenericResponse.java

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({ X_ResponseBehaviorImpl.class, Y_ResponseBehaviorImpl.class})
public class GenericResponse
{

    @XmlElement
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private ResponseBehavior responseBehavior;

    public String getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public ResponseBehavior getResponseBehavior() {
    return responseBehavior;
    }

    public void setResponseBehavior (ResponseBehavior responseBehavior) {
    this.responseBehavior = responseBehavior;
    }
}
```

ResponseBehavior.java

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.AnyTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AnyTypeAdapter.class)
public interface ResponseBehavior 
{
    void setResponse(Object value); 
}
```

X_ResponseBehaviorImpl.java

```
public class X_ResponseBehaviorImpl implements ResponseBehavior
{

 @XmlElement
 String comb10;

 @XmlElement
 String reint4;

 private void setResponse(Object value)
 {
   X_ValueDTO x_value = (X_ValueDTO) value;

   this.comb10 = x_value.getCombinacion();
   this.reint4 = x_value.getReintegro();
 }


   public void setComb10(String comb10) {
   this.comb10 = comb10;
 }


    public void setReint4(String reint4) {
    this.reint4 = reint4;
 }


}
```

Java6 includes JAXB..I try with some version (JDK6_u04,JDK6_u14...) and not solve the problem...

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Finally I didn't found any response for my problem with JAXB and GAE...but I made the functionality with this library: [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 might include JAXB, but I'm not sure it is available on GAE's JVM environment. I would suggest that you package the JAXB jars along with your app. I had a similar issue where the Rhino jars (for scripting support) were not available on the GAE production environment.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added the JAXB jars (2.1.2) with my other libraries in the build path...and i have the same problem :(

Comment: Can you paste the code for the class that is failing? The error is coming from the RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader .. My guess is that your class has an annotation that might not be available in the GAE/J environment. Or some similar error.

Comment: I edit my question... I think that the problem is inside the annotations by the interface ResponseBehavior. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @Sinffredy, can you turn up the logging levels? If you are constantly seeing the same error, then I am sure that there should be more to the exception stack trace than what you have posted. Could you turn up the log levels and locate the "caused by" for the above exception?

Comment: Hi guys...Finally I used [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to complete de funcionallity....It´s not the solution for the problem but work fine...Thanks a lot.